# Is it possible to decide when CleanUp method should be run?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium

I'm using Microsoft Test Framework - **MST**. I'd like to close the browser after the test is run. So I added a **CleanUp** method.

```
[TestCleanup]
public void CleanUp()
{
    page.Exit();
}
```

This is how the **Exit()** method is defined.

```
public void Exit(int seconds = 3)
{
    if(driver != null)
        driver.Quit();
}
```

That works for one unit test. However, when I run all the tests at once, I'm getting an exception because the framework keeps using the same driver. When the driver is destroyed, the framework is still counting on the driver that's just been destroyed.

Is it possible to decide when to destroy the **webdriver** instance? I mean, when I run only one test, the driver should be destroyed at end of that one test. And, when I run more than one, the driver should be destroyed at the of the last test. Maybe that means deciding when to call the CleanUp method. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for `ClassCleanup`.

If instead of using `TestCleanup`, you use `ClassCleanup()` the cleanup will be performed after all of the tests within that class have been run, rather than after each individual test (whether you run just 1 test, or all of them).

You may also need to look at `ClassInitialize`, depending on how you create your page/driver variables to ensure they are available during the `ClassCleanup` method.  Something like:

```
static PageType _page;

[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInit(TestContext context) {
        _page = // create it
}

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit() {
     // prepare _page for test run
}   

[ClassCleanup()]
public static void ClassCleanup() {
     _page.Exit();
}
```

Comment: It's working as intended. I've just a side question. Why this method should be static? is it by design?

Comment: @Richard77 It is by design.  I think it's to emphasize that it is only run once for the class, rather than for each test.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx